# max, over partition by, oracle, take max rownum record

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pull the maximum rownum in a partition. I am getting the below error message, so I need help to fix my SQL Query. 
I added in a row number and a row number in a partition in my SQL query. Code is below. 
I want to take the maximum over this partition and have tried changing the query a few times, but keep getting error messages, so I am getting stuck. 
I need some help.
Please see the below code and error message.

```
SELECT *,
max(rownum1) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as maxrownum1
from 
(
select
id, NAME_TYPE, NAME, EFFDT, 
rownum, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rownum ASC) AS rownum1
FROM name_table 
) a
where a.rownum1=maxrownum1
and rownum<=2000
```

Error message

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9
```

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Please share some sample data and expected output too. `rownum` is meaningless in the `order by` clause as it will be not the same for every execution of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems very curious.  You cannot refer to an alias in the `where` clause for the `select` that defines it.  So, put the definition in a subquery:

```
select t.*,
from (select id, NAME_TYPE, NAME, EFFDT, 
             rownum as rn, max(rownum) over (partition by id) as max_rownum
      from name_table 
     ) nt
where rn <= max_rownum and
      rownum <= 2000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with ordering you need `desc` :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (select nt.*
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rownum DESC) AS rownum1
      FROM name_table nt
      WHERE rownum <= 2000
     ) a
WHERE a.rownum1 = 1;
```

By this way you will get max `rownum` (assuming `rownum` has meaningful data).